# Generating signed XPI via jpm failed

Tags: linux, unix, firefox-addon-sdk, unix-timestamp, jpm

There was a problem [signing an Add-On](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Addons/Extension_Signing) via [jpm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#jpm_sign): The command

```
jpm -v sign --api-key 'user:xxxxxxxx:xxx' --api-secret xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

failed with the error message

> Error: Received bad response from the server while requesting https://addons.mozilla.org/api/v3/addons/%40addonname/versions/0.x.y/

Signing via the web interface worked.

How can this be fixed?

---

The full verbose output is

```
JPM [info] binary set to /usr/bin/firefox  
JPM [info] verbose set  
JPM [info] Checking compatability bootstrap.js and install.rdf for xpi  
Validating the manifest  
JPM [info] Creating fallbacks if they are necessary..  
Creating XPI  
JPM [info] Creating XPI...  
JPM [info] .jpmignore found  
JPM [info] Adding: /path/to/file  
[...]  
JPM [info] Adding: /path/to/another_file  
JPM [info] XPI created at /tmp/tmp-unsigned-xpi-25600yuqzFN3Alxa0/@addonname-0.x.y.xpi (121ms)  
JPM [info] Removing fallbacks if they were necessary..  
JPM [info] Creating updateRDF...  
Created XPI at /tmp/tmp-unsigned-xpi-25600yuqzFN3Alxa0/@addonname-0.x.y.xpi  
JPM [info] Created XPI for signing: /tmp/tmp-unsigned-xpi-25600yuqzFN3Alxa0/@addonname-0.x.y.xpi  
JPM [debug] [API] -{ url: 'https://addons.mozilla.org/api/v3/addons/%40addonname/versions/0.x.y/',  
  formData:   
   { upload:   
      { _readableState: [Object],  
        readable: true,  
        domain: null,  
        _events: [Object],  
        _eventsCount: 1,  
        _maxListeners: undefined,  
        path: '/tmp/tmp-unsigned-xpi-25600yuqzFN3Alxa0/@addonname-0.x.y.xpi',  
        fd: null,  
        flags: 'r',  
        mode: 438,  
        start: undefined,  
        end: undefined,  
        autoClose: true,  
        pos: undefined } },  
  headers: { Authorization: '<REDACTED>', Accept: 'application/json' } }  
JPM [debug] [API] <- { headers:   
   { allow: 'GET, PUT, HEAD, OPTIONS',  
     'content-type': 'application/json',  
     date: 'Thu, 17 Dec 2015 10:17:23 GMT',  
     server: 'nginx',  
     'set-cookie': '<REDACTED>',  
     'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000',  
     vary: 'Accept, X-Mobile, User-Agent',  
     'www-authenticate': 'JWT realm="api"',  
     'x-frame-options': 'DENY',  
     'content-length': '51',  
     connection: 'Close' },  
  response: { detail: 'Incorrect authentication credentials.' } }  
JPM [error] FAIL  
Error: Received bad response from the server while requesting https://addons.mozilla.org/api/v3/addons/%40addonname/versions/0.x.y/  

status: 401  
response: {"detail":"Incorrect authentication credentials."}  
headers: {"allow":"GET, PUT, HEAD, OPTIONS","content-type":"application/json","date":"Thu, 17 Dec 2015 10:17:23 GMT","server":"nginx","set-cookie":["multidb_pin_writes=y; expires=Thu, 17-Dec-2015 10:17:38 GMT; Max-Age=15; Path=/"],"strict-transport-security":"max-age=31536000","vary":"Accept, X-Mobile, User-Agent","www-authenticate":"JWT realm=\"api\"","x-frame-options":"DENY","content-length":"51","connection":"Close"}  

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jpm/lib/amo-client.js:85:13  
    at tryCatchReject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jpm/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:845:30)  
    at runContinuation1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jpm/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:804:4)  
    at Fulfilled.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jpm/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:592:4)  
    at Pending.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jpm/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:483:13)  
    at Scheduler._drain (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jpm/node_modules/when/lib/Scheduler.js:62:19)  
    at Scheduler.drain (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jpm/node_modules/when/lib/Scheduler.js:27:9)  
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:417:9)  
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:346:13)
```

Comment: Are you able to validate the XPI file using the [web interface](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/addons) (you should be able to validate without finalizing the submission)? Also note these posts [(1)](https://github.com/mozilla/olympia/issues/1071), [(2)](https://github.com/mozilla/olympia/issues/1072), which demonstrate that this error can occur if your local clock is off by more than 60 seconds with the Mozilla server. I'm working on an independent API to sign XPI files using their service, and their authentication is a nightmare.

Comment: @vallismortis: The web interface worked before. The clock was off by some 30 seconds. After ntpdate, signing worked. Post an answer if you would like an accept (and upvote).  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These posts ([1](https://github.com/mozilla/olympia/issues/1071)), ([2](https://github.com/mozilla/olympia/issues/1072)) show that this error can occur if your local clock is off by more than 60 seconds with the Mozilla server.

This is also documented in the [Olympia 3.0 Authentication API](http://olympia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/api/auth.html) (see `exp` parameter):

> **iat**
>
> This is a standard JWT claim indicating the issued at time. It should be a Unix epoch timestamp and must be in UTC time.
>
> **exp**
>
> This is a standard JWT claim indicating the expiration time. It should be a Unix epoch timestamp in UTC time and must be **no longer
> than 60 seconds** past the issued at time.
>
> #### Note:
>
> If you’re having trouble authenticating, make sure your system clock
> is correct and consider synchronizing it with something like NTP
> (Network Time Protocol).