# How to sign a Firefox WebExtensions?

Tags: firefox, sign, firefox-addon-webextensions

I tried to sign my extension follow [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/web-ext_command_reference#web-ext_sign) guide:

**My command:**

```
web-ext sign --api-key ##### --api-secret #####
```

But I'm got an error:

> sign: Error: Received bad response from the server while requesting
>   https://addons.mozilla.org/api/v3/addons/myextension%40example.org/versions/1.0.15/
>
> status: 401 response: {"detail":"JWT iat (issued at time) is invalid.
>   Make sure your system clock is synchronized with something like
>   TLSdate."}

My UTC time is +7

Please help me to fix this. Tks

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious but... is your system clock correct? I don't mean the time zone, I mean, if it says it's e.g. 10:01:30, is it really 10:01:30 there and not e.g. 10:09:30?

Comment: I checked in my Control Panel. I'm sure that my clock was synchronized

Comment: It's strange, that [seems to be](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332450/generating-signed-xpi-via-jpm-failed) the usual reason.

Comment: I think you will get a better response to this question in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/mozilla/web-ext/issues) for the package.